# This JS/jQuery code works in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown, execution

I have a countdown clock working perfectly in Firefox (both JS/jQuery and CSS), but when I run it on chrome, it doesn't work as expected. 
For example: When the second counter hits 40, it is supposed to change to next iteration, but it changes to 49, and then to 39, spending two seconds instead of one.
After some iterations (several minutes) it breaks.

I have no idea why is this happening since it works smoothly in FF (FF and chrome are both last version). Is it possible for Chrome code execution to differ from FF?

Here is the code:

```
var today = new Date();
var releaseD = new Date(2014,11-1,5); //11-1 -> November since it goes from 0 to 11
var diffMs = (releaseD - today); // milliseconds between now & end date
var diffDays = Math.round(diffMs / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); // days
var diffHrs = Math.round((diffMs % (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 3600000); // hours
var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % (1000 * 3600 * 24)) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
var diffSecs = Math.round((((diffMs % (1000 * 3600 * 24)) % 3600000) % 60000) / 1000 ); // seconds

var zDays = (diffDays === 0)?true:false;
var zHrs = (diffHrs === 0)?true:false;
var zMins = (diffMins === 0)?true:false;
var zSecs = (diffSecs === 0)?true:false;

$("#seconds ul.minutePlay li" ).eq(Math.floor(diffSecs/10) ).addClass("active");
$("#seconds ul.secondPlay li" ).eq((diffSecs % 10)).addClass("active");

$("#minutes ul.minutePlay li" ).eq(Math.floor(diffMins/10) ).addClass("active");
$("#minutes ul.secondPlay li" ).eq((diffMins % 10) ).addClass("active");

$("#hours ul.minutePlay li" ).eq(Math.floor(diffHrs/10) ).addClass("active");
$("#hours ul.secondPlay li" ).eq((diffHrs % 10) ).addClass("active");

$("#days ul.minutePlay li" ).eq(Math.floor(diffDays/100) ).addClass("active");
$("#days ul.secondPlay li" ).eq((Math.floor(diffDays/10)%10) ).addClass("active");
$("#days ul.thirdPlay li" ).eq((diffDays%10) ).addClass("active");


var start = new Date().getTime(),
    time = 0,
    elapsed = '0';


//controlling interval using server date
function instance()
{
    time += 1000;

    elapsed = Math.floor(time / 1000)/10;
    if(Math.round(elapsed) == elapsed) { elapsed += .0; }

    document.title = elapsed;
    clockAdvance("seconds", "secondPlay");

    var diff = (new Date().getTime() - start) - time;
    window.setTimeout(instance, (1000 - diff));
}

window.setTimeout(instance, 1000);

function clockAdvance(which, where) {
    $("body" ).removeClass("play");

    var aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li.active");
    if (zDays && zHrs && zMins && zSecs){
        alert("END");
    } else if (aa.is(":first-child")) {
        $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").removeClass("before");
        aa.addClass("before").removeClass("active");
        switch (which) {
            case "seconds":
                if (where === "secondPlay"){
                    aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").eq(9);
                    clockAdvance("seconds", "minutePlay");
                } else {
                    aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").eq(5);
                    clockAdvance("minutes", "secondPlay");
                }
                break;
            case "minutes":
                if (where === "secondPlay"){
                    aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").eq(9);
                    clockAdvance("minutes", "minutePlay");
                } else {
                    aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").eq(5);
                    clockAdvance("hours", "secondPlay");
                }
                break;
            case "hours":
                if (where === "secondPlay"){
                    if ($("#" + which + " ul.minutePlay li.active .up .inn" ).html() == '0') {
                        aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").eq(3);
                    } else {
                        aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").eq(9);
                    }
                    clockAdvance("hours", "minutePlay");
                } else {
                    aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").eq(2);
                    clockAdvance("days", "thirdPlay");
                }
                break;
            case "days":
                aa = $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").eq(9);
                if (where === "thirdPlay"){
                    clockAdvance("days", "secondPlay");
                } else if (where=== "secondPlay"){
                    clockAdvance("days", "minutePlay");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        aa.addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");
    }
    else {
        $("#" + which + " ul." + where + " li").removeClass("before");
        aa.addClass("before")
            .removeClass("active")
            .prev("li")
            .addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");
    }
};
```

That code act on a HTML structure similar to this one (I am only showing you the 'seconds' structure since it's quite huge)

```
      <div id="reloj" class="reloj">
            <div id="seconds" class="container">
                                <ul class="flip minutePlay">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">0</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">0</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">1</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">1</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">2</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">2</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">3</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">3</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">4</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">4</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">5</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">5</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="flip secondPlay">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">0</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">0</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">1</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">1</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">2</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">2</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">3</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">3</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">4</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">4</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">5</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">5</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">6</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">6</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">7</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">7</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">8</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">8</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="up">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">9</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="down">
                                                <div class="shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="inn">9</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I structured it like this to better animate it via CSS class styles. Here's the CSS:

```
    #reloj {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
}

#days{
    width: 330px;
}

ul.flip {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 90px;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 87px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

ul.flip li {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

ul.flip li:first-child {
    z-index: 2;
}

ul.flip li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    perspective: 200px;
}

ul.flip li a div {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.flip li a div .shadow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

ul.flip li a div.up {
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    top: 0;
}

ul.flip li a div.up:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top:44px;
    left:0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

ul.flip li a div.down {
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    bottom: 0;
}

ul.flip li a div div.inn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

ul.flip li a div.up div.inn {
    top: 0;

}

ul.flip li a div.down div.inn {
    bottom: 0;
}

/* PLAY */

body.play ul li.before {
    z-index: 3;
}

body.play ul li.active {
    animation: asd .2s .2s linear both;
    z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes asd {
    0% {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    5% {
        z-index: 4;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 4;
    }
}

body.play ul li.active .down {
    z-index: 2;
    animation: turn .2s .2s linear both;
}

@keyframes turn {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}

body.play ul li.before .up {
    z-index: 2;
    animation: turn2 .2s linear both;
}

@keyframes turn2 {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
}

/* SHADOW */

body.play ul li.before .up .shadow {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    animation: show .2s linear both;
}

body.play ul li.active .up .shadow {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    animation: hide .2s .1s linear both;
}

/*DOWN*/

body.play ul li.before .down .shadow {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    animation: show .2s linear both;
}

body.play ul li.active .down .shadow {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    animation: hide .2s .1s linear both;
}

@keyframes show {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes hide {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

There is a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pbartrina/uYJUq/

Thank you for taking a look at it.

Comment: I've found this alternative -> http://demo.cnanney.com/apple-counter-revisited/
It's working well on webkit. What do you think?

Comment: would you mind sharing the css as well so we can examine the application state? Here is a JS fiddle of what you have given us so far so you can put it here if you like. http://jsfiddle.net/9uAqV/

Comment: @Gabriel I added the CSS for4 you, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pbartrina/uYJUq/

Comment: probably also a good idea to create a jsbin with this code so that people can fire it up in their browser by following a link

Comment: I think we need a fiddle/jsbin/codepen or something as the code is non-trivial. Btw `zDays = !!diffDays`, `zHrs = !!diffHrs` bit shorter

Comment: @DominicTobias There is a fiddle in the third comment. I'll add it to the main post.

Comment: It looks like the problem comes from `Math.round()` method and how is interpreted by each browser. I'd probably have to write my own round method to avoid that. I'll post it if it fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-webkit-` to all `@keyframes` (`@-webkit-keyframes`), `animation` and `transform` properties of your CSS. This worked for me.

BTW, please [lint](http://www.jslint.com/) this code with some [tool](http://www.jshint.com/)...